# How to make Multiple requests in parallel to a webservice in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I need to call 3 WCF services as below,

```
var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var resultJson1 = client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetAvailableProductsByContact",
                                         jsonser1);
var resultJson2= client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetMemberProductsByContact",
                                         jsonser2);

var resultJson3= client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetCoachProductsByContact",
                                         jsonser3);
```

This takes a lot of time to get results and display on the page. Can anyone help me how I could execute them in parallel?

Comment: Put this into another class and multithread it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [task parallelism library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

```
Task<string>[] taskArray = new Task<string>[]
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            var json = client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetAvailableProductsByContact",
                                     jsonser1);
            return json;
        }),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            var json = client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetMemberProductsByContact",
                                     jsonser2);
            return json;
        }),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            var json = client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetCoachProductsByContact",
                                     jsonser3);
            return json;
        }),
    };

// the request for .Result is blocking and waits until each task
// is completed before continuing; however, they should also all
// run in parallel instead of sequentially.
var resultJson1 = taskArray[0].Result;
var resultJson2 = taskArray[1].Result;
var resultJson3 = taskArray[2].Result;
```

Or alternatively, since your requests are all very similar, differing only by the url and upload string, you can use LINQ `AsParallel` array processing:

```
var requests = new [] {
    new { Url = "http://localhost:45868/Product/GetAvailableProductsByContact", Input = jsonser1 },
    new { Url = "http://localhost:45868/Product/GetMemberProductsByContact", Input = jsonser2 },
    new { Url = "http://localhost:45868/Product/GetCoachProductsByContact", Input = jsonser3 },
};
var result = requests.AsParallel().Select(req => {
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var json = client.UploadString(req.Url, req.Input);
    return json;
}).ToArray();

// when above code has finished running, all tasks are completed
var resultJson1 = result[0];
var resultJson2 = result[1];
var resultJson3 = result[2];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This indeed would speed up the process.

Comment: I did not test any of the code above.  Let me know if it generates compile-time or runtime errors.  You may also want to familiarize yourself with `AggregateException` for dealing with errors when one or more of the requests cannot be completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [begin/end pattern:](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/executing-asynchronous-web-services/)

This example shows you how to call two ws in parallell. You can extend the idea to N services.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `Task` that executes each of your calls ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx#S8))

You could try doing the following

First create a `Task<String>` for each of your calls

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

Task<String> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    client.UploadString("http://localhost:45868/Product/GetAvailableProductsByContact",
                                         jsonser1);
});
```

Rinse and repeat for the other 2

Afterwards you can join on the execution of the 3 `Task<String>` by calling `task1.Value`, `task2.Value` and `task3.Value` which will return a `String`

Comment: @mellamokb beat me to it! His/her 2nd answer is great.

Comment: Note that you want to be careful about sharing the same instance of the `client` across the parallel tasks.  `WebClient` instances are not declared thread safe, which is why I explicitly go to the effort in my examples to create separate instances of `WebClient` objects for each service call.