# Loop with multiple HTTPWebRequest and JSON deserializer slow

Tags: c#, asana, asana-api

**Problem**

I have a C# application where I have around 40 to 50 different Asana Task ID's. I want details for each ID so what I do is make a request in a for loop for each ID. The data is in JSON format:

```
// For each result in the data.
foreach (var result in results["data"])
{
    // ID for each Asana task in the data.
    string id = (string)result["id"];

    // Deserialize the JSON data so we can use it with an object and its properties.
    deserialize.SetJsonData(requestAsana.getSingleAsanaTask(id));

    // Add data to the list.
    asanaDataList.Add(deserialize.Data);
}
```

The `SetJsonData` method deserializes the JSON data:

```
    private AsanaRootData root = new AsanaRootData();
    public string jsonData;
    public string SetJsonData(string json)
    {
        this.jsonData = json;

        root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AsanaRootData>(jsonData);         

        return json;
    }
```

And the `getSingleAsanaTask` method is the method doing requests to Asana with given ID:

```
public string getSingleAsanaTask(string taskID)
    {
        try
        {
            // Make a request variable with URL and ID.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(taskURL + taskID);
            // Speed up requests.
            request.Proxy = null;

            // Encode authentication value.
            String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(auth));

            // Add authentication to header.
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            // Response variable.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            return readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\nInvalid Asana task ID\n");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**Questions**

Sometimes I can have more than 50 tasks I want to load, still it can take up to 20 seconds. Is there a way to increase performance, or am I perhaps doing it wrong?

- I can see that I am creating a new `HTTPWebRequest` variable for each request, does that matter?
- Could it be my deserializing method that slows everything down?

**What have I tried?**

- `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = connectionLimit;`
- `req.Proxy = null;`
- `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`
- Threading for the `setJsonData` method.
- `Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();` where the requests took around 40% of the time.

**Narrowed down to**

- The following line is taking half of the time: `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Comment: Is it possible to query the webservice parallel? That might speed up a lot

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844203/how-to-make-multiple-requests-in-parallel-to-a-webservice-in-c-sharp 
Did not help

Comment: Have you timed how long the webserver needs to answer? It may well be that it just takes that long.

Comment: No, I can try that

Comment: I tried again, 16 seconds for the operation, and the requests took 8 seconds of that time.